# Re-write old url to new url Asp.Net

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, dns, web-config, umbraco

I have 2 domains pointing to the same Umbraco application:

```
oldexample.com
newexample.com
```

I want my application to change the URL from:

```
oldexample.com/... 
TO 
newexample.com/...
```

when people visit the oldexample.com.

In my web.config, I've placed this, but to no effect:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect old-domain to new-domain" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^oldexample.com$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.newexample.com/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\." />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="localhost" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

What am I doing wrong?

*// The application is hosted in Azure web sites.* And both URLs are hostnames assigned to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect oldexample.com to newexample.com" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.oldexample\.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^oldexample\.com$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.newexample.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>    
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Note: when putting in the [OLD URL], don't include the **http://** as that will not work.